# How to make CreateProccess and pipe act exactly as normal cmd pipe

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to create software to accurately imitate the pipe of the CMD.

In cmd when i typed for example :

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ofb -d -in encrypted.bin -iv a2b050be9463 -K 6ba62eb7bb2ccace -nopad|mplayer -
```

then openssl pipe the contant directly to mplayer and when you seek to the end of the file , mplayer closed and every thing works fine.

I try to imitate the pipe of the CMD like this:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION piSource, piDest;
HANDLE hPipeIn, hPipeOut;
HANDLE hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
STARTUPINFOW suSource, suDest;
ZeroMemory(&suSource, sizeof(suSource));
ZeroMemory(&suDest, sizeof(suDest));
suSource.cb = suDest.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);
suSource.dwFlags = suDest.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;


//create a pipe
if (CreatePipe(&hPipeIn, &hPipeOut, &sa, 0) == 0)
{
    return GetLastError();
}

suSource.hStdInput = hIn;                //hin=STD_INPUT_HANDLE input of source = input
suSource.hStdError = suSource.hStdOutput = hPipeOut;//output and error of source = input of pipe
suDest.hStdInput = hPipeIn;                 //destInput = pipe output
suDest.hStdError = suDest.hStdOutput = hOut;    //hout = STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = output of destination




//to hide the new window
suDest.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE; 

//open 2 process and pipe them 1 to another
//openssl proccess
std::wcout << opensslProgram << L" " << openSslFullParameters << std::endl; 
LPWSTR param1 = const_cast<LPWSTR>(openSslFullParameters.c_str());
if (CreateProcess(opensslProgram.c_str(), param1, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &suSource, &piSource) == 0)
{
    return GetLastError();
}

CloseHandle(piSource.hThread);

//mplayer need to read from stdout of openssl       
LPWSTR param2 = const_cast<LPWSTR>(mplayerParameters.c_str());

if (CreateProcess(mplayerProgram.c_str(), param2, NULL, NULL, TRUE,/*NULL*/ CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &suDest, &piDest) == 0) {//CREATE_NO_WINDOW
    return GetLastError();
}


CloseHandle(piDest.hThread);
HANDLE hArray[2];
hArray[0] = piSource.hProcess;
hArray[1] = piDest.hProcess;
WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hArray, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

My problem is that my program and pipe of the CMD does not behave the same.

In my program, when the film comes to end MPLAYER stuck, (he is running some kind of a loop of the film last frame, and then the screen freezes and the software stops (poorly - crash)), it made me think that probably I did not use the right flags to open the process or that I might have a mistake in opening the pipes.

How can I make sure that my program and the pipes of the CMD will behave exactly the same?

Comment: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx) as a starting point.

Comment: thank you , but i build this base on reading in this article ... , i just can't find what i do rung ...

Comment: @adamsmith There are things that article's code is doing with the pipes that you are not doing in your code. Read the article again more carefully.

Comment: Do `openSslFullParameters`  and `mplayerParameters` include the application name as the first token?  If not, the first token will be ignored.  Also, you're casting away the const-ness of the output of `cstr()`, which is technically a violation of the language standard.  Lastly, you're not closing your copy of the pipe handles after launching the child processes.  That may mean that `mplayer` has no way to tell when `openssl` is finished sending data.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Thank you so much , the main problem was that i forgat to close the pipes handle . , now i have a little problem left , the fule closed in the end but he stuck for a second , he play the last frame 1 time more and only then get close , what can be the source of this problem? (in a normal usb pipe its not happening)